# jQuery: animate opacity to 0 then fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function set up that animates the opacity of an element to 0 as you scroll, what I want though is after this function as finished (the opacity is at 0), then the element fades out (i.e. you never see it again). The function is a bit buggy though and is fading out too early, I have a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hcm4qg4/

My markup is as follows:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var height = $(window).height();



  var myEvent = function() {
    $('.logo_container, .slogan').css({
      'opacity': ((height - scrollTop) / height)
    });
  };
  $.when(myEvent()).done(function() {
    $('.logo_container, .slogan').fadeOut();
  });

});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The function `fadeOut()` already does the same thing... Why do you need to set the opacity to 0 and then again fade it out?

Comment: I guess you are doing it wrong. `:(` The opacity must be set as a function of the scroll and timing. Not right...

Comment: @PraveenKumar I can control the opacity animation from 1 to 0 on scroll but I can control that with a FadeOut thus the reason I want to run this at the end after the opacity has reduced to 0. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just `.hide()` after opacity is 0?

Comment: @PraveenKumar can you demonstrate in the jSFiddle?

Comment: That's what I am trying, but something is not right.

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes, that's the problem I'm having, can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jquery` `animate` function to change `opacity` with animation. In animate function callback hide the element if opacity reaches to `0` like below.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var height = $(window).height();

    $('.logo_container, .slogan').animate({
      'opacity': ((height - scrollTop) / height)
    }, function() {
       if (this.style.opacity <= 0)
           $(this).hide();
    });
});
```